# Restore a database changing the schema on DB2

Tags: db2, db2-luw

I have a database dump where the table schema is db2inst2. I would like to restore this database on a different server, but using db2inst1 as the destination schema.

Is there a way to do it using db2 restore command?

If not, is there a way to change the schema of all tables after the restore?

Comment: what kid of dump do you have ? dump or backup. "db2 restore" restore a backup taken by "db2 backup". a backup is a copy of the tablespaces (not tables) so when you restore a backup you cann't change schema of tables, you can change directory where the tablespace will be restored. if you have a dump done by db2move, you can change change the schema before you import the data

Comment: @mshabou thanks... I have a "db2 backup", so I cannot restore it changing the schema at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the ADMIN_COPY_SCHEMA procedure to copy all objects from one schema to another.

Once completed and you verify everything you can use ADMIN_DROP_SCHEMA to drop the old one.